# Excel VBA: Matching sum values with coding to apply rules

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a loop that goes for each account (that part is easy), apply another filter (also easy) and with that done, starts to look at the number in the spreadsheet, column ´H´ - ´Importe´ (picture below) and applies some

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I need a way that this macro would look at the numbers in column H, and when the sum is equal to zero, writes ´Closed´ for both in the column J - Ref.

Please see the example below:

[image]

In this case, for Closed_1 I have the values that are the same, only one for each.

But in the case of the Closed_2 I have 3 values that summed are equals to the sum of another value, totalizing zero.

```
(11.906) + (11.612) + (137) + 23.655 = 0
```

Any clues on how do I achieve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a VBA macro for this as it sounds like you can do this just in Excel.  I'm not entirely clear where the extra figures are coming from, but what I suggest is that you have hidden helper columns that perform intermediate checks.  The first helper sums two values, the second sums three, and so forth, while the last one summarises those results.  For example, if your helper cells are in J2, K2 and L2, then M2 should look like this:

```
=IF(J2=0,"Closed_1",IF(K2=0,"Closed_2",IF(L2=0,"Closed_3","Open")))
```

Obviously you will need to adapt this to your specific needs, but hopefully it will give you some useful ideas.